# Are there any good Recipe Suggestion Web Apps?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a web app that will allow me to input a bunch of ingredients I have lying around and will output some recipes I could make with all or most of the ingredients.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [www.supercook.com](http://www.supercook.com) is exactly what you are looking for.  It sorts recipes by how many of the ingredients you have and what you'd need to go to the store for (if any).  You can also have it exclude items you don't like.

> Supercook is a new recipe search
>   engine that finds recipes you can make
>   with only the ingredients you have at
>   home. To begin, simply start adding
>   ingredients you have in the green box
>   on the top left. The more ingredients
>   you add, the better the results will
>   be.be.

Answer (score 4):

yes.

http://allrecipes.com/Search/Ingredients.aspx
http://www.supercook.com/
http://www.bigoven.com/leftoverwizard2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:  http://www.cookingbynumbers.com/frames.html

It asks you what ingredients you have on hand (using checklist of about 50 items), and then offers a list of recipes you can make with them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that http://www.recipezaar.com/ is really good for tasty recipes.  It allows you to search by ingredients from a database of about half a million recipes rated by a community

Answer (score 0):

[Google's Recipe View](http://www.google.com/landing/recipes/) can suggest recipes based on ingredients you input.

It lets you [filter the results](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/slice-and-dice-your-recipe-search.html) by ingredients, cook time, or calories.